# Monthly retention in Amazon redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to calculate monthly retention rate in `Amazon Redshift` and have come up with the following query:

`Query 1`

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM activity.created_at) AS Year,
       EXTRACT(month FROM activity.created_at) AS Month,
       COUNT(DISTINCT activity.member_id) AS active_users,
       COUNT(DISTINCT future_activity.member_id) AS retained_users,
       COUNT(DISTINCT future_activity.member_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT activity.member_id)::float AS retention
FROM ads.fbs_page_view_staging activity
  LEFT JOIN ads.fbs_page_view_staging AS future_activity
         ON activity.mongo_id = future_activity.mongo_id
AND datediff ('month',activity.created_at,future_activity.created_at) = 1
GROUP BY Year,
         Month
ORDER BY Year,
         Month
```

For some reason this query returns `zero` `retained_users` and `zero` `retention`. I'd appreciate any help regarding why this may be happening or maybe a completely different query for monthly retention would work.

I modified the query as per another SO post and here it goes:

`Query 2`

```
WITH t AS (
   SELECT member_id
         ,date_trunc('month', created_at) AS month
         ,count(*) AS item_transactions
         ,lag(date_trunc('month', created_at)) OVER (PARTITION BY  member_id
                                           ORDER BY date_trunc('month', created_at)) 
          = date_trunc('month', created_at) - interval '1 month'
            OR NULL AS repeat_transaction
   FROM   ads.fbs_page_view_staging
   WHERE  created_at >= '2016-01-01'::date
   AND    created_at <  '2016-04-01'::date -- time range of interest.
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   )
SELECT month
      ,sum(item_transactions) AS num_trans
      ,count(*) AS num_buyers
      ,count(repeat_transaction) AS repeat_buyers
      ,round(
          CASE WHEN sum(item_transactions) > 0
             THEN count(repeat_transaction) / sum(item_transactions) * 100
             ELSE 0
          END, 2) AS buyer_retention
FROM   t
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

This query gives me the following error:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
WITH t AS (
   SELECT member_id
         ,date_trunc('month', created_at) AS month
         ,count(*) AS item_transactions
         ,lag(date_trunc('m...

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Interval values with month or year parts are not supported
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Interval values with month or year parts are not supported
  code:      8001
  context:   interval months: "1"
  query:     616822
  location:  cg_constmanager.cpp:145
  process:   padbmaster [pid=15116]
  -----------------------------------------------;
```

I have a feeling that `Query 2` would fare better than `Query 1`, so I'd prefer to fix the error on that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think your problem with Query 1 is that you've put the interval condition `datediff ('month',activity.created_at,future_activity.created_at) = 1` into the JOIN. Don't think that would work. So the join is failing, and hence you are getting NULL on the right side of the join, resulting in zero counts.

What happens when you move the condition into "WHERE"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query 1 looks good. I tried similar one. See below. You are using self join on table (ads.fbs_page_view_staging) and the same column (created_at). Assuming mongo_id is unique, the `datediff('month'....)` will always return 0 and `datediff ('month',activity.created_at,future_activity.created_at) = 1` will always be false.

```
-- Count distinct events of join_col_id that have lapsed for one month.
SELECT count(distinct E.join_col_id) dist_ct
FROM public.fact_events E
JOIN public.dim_table Z
  ON E.join_col_id = Z.join_col_id
WHERE datediff('month', event_time, sysdate) = 1;

-- 2771654 -- dist_ct
```

Comment: That's exactly right, I was joining on the wrong column, should have been `member_id`, not the `mongo_id`. Silly mistake on my end. Thanks for pointing that out.